# Swashbuckle, Swagger Pattern and Format annotation or XML comment

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

I'am trying to add the format and/or pattern keywords in my Swagger documentation. I'am using Swashbuckle and currenlty I'am using XML Comments to insert descriptions for my different fields. For example:
The controller:

```
/// <summary>
/// Shows a list with states
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">The state ID</param>
/// <returns>Offers the state</returns>
[HttpGet("id", Name = "Get")]
public async Task<ActionResult<State>> GetState(string id)
{
State result = GetState(id);
return Ok(result);
}
```

I want the swagger documentation to show the pattern keyword with the regex expression:

```
'^[{(]?[0-9A-F]{8}[-]?(?:[0-9A-F]{4}[-]?){3}[0-9A-F]{12}[)}]?$'
```

Is it possible to add this documentation while using XML comments or annotations. I'd like to ask the same for the format keyword. For example:
'format: date-time'

Are these things possible using XML comments or annotations with Swashbuckle to auto generate Swagger documentation or would this require a static swagger file?

Comment: Is your question just how do I put RegEx into my Xml Comments?

Comment: @matt_lethargic Yes I want to put a regex pattern into my Xml Comments so it would show up in my Swagger documentation file generated by Swashbuckle. At the moment the Description in <param name="id">The state ID</param> shows up but if I add <pattern> "{regexstring}" </patern> nothing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the project there is an example how to use it for models:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/5489aca0d2dd7946f5569341f621f581720d4634/Swashbuckle.Dummy.Core/Controllers/MetadataAnnotatedTypesController.cs#L21

```
public class PaymentMetadata
{
    [Required]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    [Required, RegularExpression("^[3-6]?\\d{12,15}$")]
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }

    [Required, Range(1, 12)]
    public int ExpMonth { get; set; }

    [Required, Range(14, 99)]
    public int ExpYear { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500, MinimumLength = 10)]
    public string Note { get; set; }
}
```

---

For a primitive like in your case I'm not sure that is fully supported, you can try with something like:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<State>> GetState([RegularExpression("PATTERN")]string id)
```

If that does not work you can inject it using an [IDocumentFilter](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/search?q=IDocumentFilter)

Comment: Thank you that worked. Adding it in the function parameter field worked to.

Comment: Great, unfortunately the version of the swagger-ui used in swashbuckle is not taking advantage of that, there was some movement to upgrade: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/pull/1132 but did not get any traction... I started my own project based on that: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swagger-Net/ and I'm using the latest UI, try it if you have time.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried adding the regex into one of my projects that uses swagger and it worked fine

```
/// <param name="customerId">^[{(]?[0-9A-F]{8}[-]?(?:[0-9A-F]{4}[-]?){3}[0-9A-F]{12}[)}]?$</param>
```

Comment: I think that will show in the example not in the pattern keyword