# Swashbuckle use format identifier via XML comment in .NET application

Tags: asp.net, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm trying to get the format identifier printed on the Swagger UI which is stated on their homepage. In the auto-generated json file it should look like in this example:
[image: format property example]

The way of how I'd like to achieve that is via xml comments in my view model class. This works well for tags like `example`, `summary` etc., but there is no tag like `format`. It would be important for me to state that the string we are awaiting here in the API must be in a certain format.

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53315885/swashbuckle-swagger-pattern-and-format-annotation-or-xml-comment), but there hasn't been an answer for the format identifier.

How can I achieve this?
Versions used: .NET 7 and Swashbuckle v 6.4.0.

My view model looks like that:

```
public class MeasurementViewModel {
    /// <example>20.01.2003</example>
    /// <format>dd.mm.yyyy</format>  <-- this is what I would expect but doesn't have any effect
    [JsonProperty("patient_birthdate")] public string? PatientDateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution thanks to that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74864021/8932539).

I added the additional package "Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations" via NuGet and in my Startup.cs where I configure the Swagger generation I enable the annotations:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    ...
    c.EnableAnnotations();
}
```

In my ViewModel I can now use the following annotation:

```
/// <example>20.01.2002</example>
[JsonProperty("patient_birthdate"), SwaggerSchema(Format = "dd.mm.yyyy")] public string? PatientDateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

.. which results in a beautiful documentation:

[image]